# I am unable to see addEventListener event in dev tools MicrosoftEdge Version 112.0.1722.34 (Official build) (64-bit)

Tags: javascript

```js
let x = document.createElement('p');
x.style.background = "aqua";
x.textContent = ' Click inside the box to Change background color ';
x.id = "para1";
console.log(x);
document.body.appendChild(x);

function changeBackgroundColor(e) {
  e.target.style.background = "yellow";
}
document.getElementById("para1").addEventListener("click", changeBackgroundColor);
```

```css
p {
  border: solid green 2px;
  margin-right: 65em;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

Not able to see event listener in Microsoft edge tool (event listener has been added to code)

[image: pic1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is attached to an element. If you select this element then you can see its event handlers. You don't have to pause the code for that.

[image: devtools element's event handlers]